# Rendering another template from a button click in Django

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

I have following template files in my django project:

1. base.html
2. base_test1.html
3. base_test2.html

Here both `base_test1.html` and `base_test2.html` [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-extends) `base.html`. My home page renders `base_test1.html`. In my home page, I have a button which when pressed should render `base_test2.html`. How should I achieve this?

I have been trying to use jQuery ajax call so that when the button is pressed, I call the corresponding view in the `views.py` of my application. But that doesn't seem to be working since the ajax call just returns the html page to the request rather than  rendering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create another url, view for 2nd template which I think you have done.
- Make button as link to this url. So that when the button is pressed, page with 2nd template is rendered.

If you want to use ajax, the `base_test2.html` should not return complete HTML page. But just some block in the html page, which you replace in the original page.