# Load several templates into a base template in django on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, django, templates, jinja2

I have several apps (app1.html, app2.html etc.) and a base.html that has (let's say) 4 placeholders. Now I want to enable the user by clicking on one of the placeholders to choose from these apps and load them into that placeholder. Here's a simple example with js for more clarity: https://jsfiddle.net/eja4t0gb/15/

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div id="module-1" class="">
      This is module 1.
      <button id="load-1">Load Module</button>
    </div>
    ---
    <div id="module-2" class="">
      This is module 2.
      <button id="load-2">Load Module</button>
    </div>
    ---
    <div id="module-3" class="">
      This is module 3.
      <button id="load-3">Load Module</button>
    </div>
    ---
    <div id="module-4" class="">
      This is module 4.
      <button id="load-4">Load Module</button>
    </div>
    --- ---
    <div id="chooser">
      Choose an App.
      <button id="app-1">App-1</button>
      <button id="app-2">App-2</button>
      <button id="app-3">App-3</button>
      <button id="app-4">App-4</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var chosenModule = null;
document.getElementById("chooser").style.display = "none";

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  document.getElementById("load-" + i).addEventListener("click",
    function() {
      chosenModule = i;
      document.getElementById("chooser").style.display = "block";
    });
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  document.getElementById("app-" + i).addEventListener("click",
    function() {
      loadApp(i);
      document.getElementById("chooser").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("app-" + i).style.display = "none";
    });
}

function loadApp(i) {
  document.getElementById('module-' + chosenModule).innerHTML = "App" + i;
}
```

Here's my question: How would I implement this with django templates/Jinja2?

Now I have seen this post: [Django: Loading another template on click of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864559/django-loading-another-template-on-click-of-a-button), however, there the goal was to load a completely new page. I on the other hand want to additionally load the apps with all their resources only after the button click, without having to reload the page itself.
I know about {% include 'app.html' %}, but how can I tell the base.html to only interpret this after the click of a button/via js code? Or is is 'include' the wrong approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Django templates work on HTTP protocol which is **stateless**. It mean you can not get other template once you have rendered it!But, you can use ajax request to fetch django template from your webapp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Do you happen to know any good examples I can have a look on about this matter? Or maybe give a simple one? The only tutorials I found don't fetch templates, but compare user input with data in the database.

Comment: Okay, you could find one example blog for [Jquery + Django rest API from here](https://medium.com/@_christopher/basic-web-app-with-django-rest-framework-and-jquery-ajax-c3a6a2ce3188). It will figure out basic concept that match your requirements